# calculating accuracy (in lstm model)

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to get my accuracy, and I have this code:

```py
            num_correct = 0.0
            for inputs, labels in dataloader(
            valid_features, valid_labels, batch_size=batch_size, sequence_length=20):

                top_val, top_class = torch.exp(output).topk(1)
                num_correct += torch.sum(top_class.squeeze() == labels)
#...
            print(#...,
                  "Accuracy: {:.3f}".format(num_correct*1.0 / len(valid_labels) *1.0)
```

It always prints 0.000, so I decided to print the raw values going into `num_correct`:
`print(top_class.squeeze(), labels)`

```
tensor([ 1,  3,  3,  ...,  3,  4,  3], device='cuda:0') tensor([ 1,  1,  3,  ...,  3,  3,  3], device='cuda:0')
tensor([ 4,  3,  1,  ...,  4,  4,  3], device='cuda:0') tensor([ 4,  3,  1,  ...,  4,  4,  3], device='cuda:0')
tensor([ 2,  4,  2,  ...,  4,  4,  4], device='cuda:0') tensor([ 3,  4,  1,  ...,  4,  4,  4], device='cuda:0')
tensor([ 0,  1,  3,  ...,  2,  3,  0], device='cuda:0') tensor([ 0,  1,  3,  ...,  2,  2,  0], device='cuda:0')
```

these appear pretty highly accurate. So .. I could extract this out to numpy and be done with it, but there is a pytorch way.

Comment: what is `valid_labels`?

Comment: Hey @DerekG thanks for that quetsion, it didnt dawn on me when I replaced that line with a "#..." that you would not be seeing something essential

Comment: so for each batch of labels, I keep their sum in num_correct, then at the end, I divide by the total number of labels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
num_correct += torch.sum(torch.eq(top_class.squeeze(), labels)).item()
```